# About MS Visual Sourcesafe 6

Tags: sourcesafe-6.0

My company uses Visual Sourcesafe 6 on an old project.  One of the system that was used got damaged beyond repair with few of the items still checked-out.  Now I am having a problem working on those.

Is there a way I can check them in by some other means?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can break the lock that is held by the user that checked them out, look to the admin tool to do that.

Otherwise, run analyze (with -v4 option, IIRC) and then migrate to something else. Corrupting the DB is something that happens too often with VSS.

Comment: :: I couldn't find the option to  break the lock on the admin tool.  Do you know where it is located at?